# Python 3: check if the entire list is inside another list

Tags: python, list

Let's say I have 2 lists:
`a = [6,7,8,9,10]`
`b = [1,3,4,6,7,8,9,10]`

I have a function that is used to find out if *list a* can be found in *list b*. If it is found, then it returns **True**. In my case it should return **True** because *list a* can be found at the end of *list b*. *List a* never changes and always contains the same numbers, whereas *list b* accepts numbers from the user and then uses `sorted()` method to sort numbers in ascending order. I should also add that the order does matter.

I have searched around and could find a subset method, which looks like this: `set(a).issubset(set(b)))` as well as using `in` method. Both of them did not work for me.

**UPDATE**:
Using `set(a).issubset(set(b)))` for some reason always returns True. For example, if
  `a = [1,1]` and   `b = [0,1,2,3,4,5]` then using subset method returns True, even though 1,1 cannot be found in b. I'm not looking if 1 is inside the list, I'm looking if 1,1 is inside the list.

Using `in` method when
`a = [6,7,8,9,10]`
`b = [1,3,4,6,7,8,9,10]`  returns False.

Comment: Why didn't they work?

Comment: When you say they did not work, what do you mean?  Did they not give the correct answer, or did they cause the program to error out?  Can you show us what you are currently implementing?

Comment: You should look at the documentation for [set](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set).  Every element in a set must be *unique*, so `a = set([1,1])` only has the element `1`, in it, and `1` is in `[0,1,2,3,4,5]`

Comment: but in set theory the set (1,1) is a subset of the set (1,2) as 1 == 1... so you're not looking for sets at all then.

Comment: When I asked "Can you show us what you are currently implementing?", I meant actually show your code.  Simply stating that "using the `in` method when `a = [6,7,8,9,10]` and `b = [1,3,4,6,7,8,9,10]` returns False" doesn't explain how you actually implemented this.  Maybe you have a syntax problem that we can help you resolve that you are unaware of.

Comment: you cannot use sets for this  as they will remove duplicates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't say how important speed was.  So I'd wrap the functionality in a class, so that you can hide the complications from the rest of your code if you need to get fancier later.  Since

> List a never changes and always contains the same numbers

it makes sense to pass `a` to the class constructor.  Here's one way:

```
class ASearcher:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    def isin(self, b):
        a = self.a
        a0 = a[0]
        lena = len(a)
        i = 0
        try:
            while 1:
                j = b.index(a0, i) # raises ValueError if not found
                if a == b[j: j+lena]:
                    return True
                i = j+1  # start search over 1 position later
        except ValueError:
            return False
```

Then, e.g.,

```
asearch = ASearcher([6,7,8,9,10])
print asearch.isin([1,3,4,6,7,8,9,10])
```

prints `True`.

There is no function in the standard library to do what you want here, so you need to roll your own.  The class above implements a method that does the searching, in B, for the first element of A, "at C speed".  It will probably be "fast enough" - maybe ;-)

Comment: Really nice explanation. Other answers were also useful to me. Thank you everyone, the problem is now solved

Answer (score 1):

If the values in `a` and `b` happen to be in the range 0-255, you can use this trick

```
>>> a = [6,7,8,9,10]
>>> b = [1,3,4,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> bytearray(a) in bytearray(b)
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brute force way:

```
a = [6,7,8,9,10]
b = [1,3,4,6,7,8,9,10]

def check_if_in_list(a, b):
    for i in xrange(len(b) - len(a) + 1):
        if a == b[i : i + len(a)]:
            return True
    return False
```

Result:

```
>>> check_if_in_list(a, b)
True
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, you're interested in knowing whether `a` is a contiguous subsequence of `b`.  So:

```
>>> a = [6,7,8,9,10]
>>> b = [1,3,4,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> any(b[i:i+len(a)] == a for i in range(len(b)-len(a)+1))
True
```

This isn't the most efficient approach, but it'll often be fast enough in practice.

Answer (score 0):

Something you find useful

```
idx = -1
notfound = False
for index, item in enumerate(b):
    if item == a[0]:
        idx = index
if idx == -1:
    notfound = True
for i in xrange(idx, len(a) + idx):
    if len(b) <= i or a[i - idx] != b[i]:
        notfound = True
print "Not found: ", notfound
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to loop over each and every index. Just find the first element and then see of the remainder elements match.

You could do something along these lines:

```
a = [6,7,8,9,10]
b = [1,3,4,6,7,8,9,10]

def liAinliB(a, b):
    try:
        ind=b.index(a[0])
    except ValueError:
        return False

    return b[ind:ind+len(a)]==a

print(liAinliB(a, b))
```